# can't install the ensembl-vep newest release on conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install ensembl-vep:`conda search ensembl-vep` shows the latest release available is 110.1. However, when I install it via `conda install -c bioconda ensembl-vep -y` the release `105` is installed instead. when I specidically give the version `conda install -c bioconda ensembl-vep=110 -y` or `conda install -c bioconda ensembl-vep=110.1 -y` it triggers many perl related conflicts. I updated my conda before everything as in [conda/tasks](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-conda.html#updating-conda-to-the-current-version) and still no success. These conflicts are both on ubuntu and OSX.
I'm not sure how to solve this problem, any help will be highly appreciated

thank you very much

Here is the error:

```
conda install -c bioconda ensembl-vep=110.1 -y
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: | 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                   /  

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
perl-dbd-mysql -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9']
perl-text-csv -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<6.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0']
perl-io-compress -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9']
perl-io-compress -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0']
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.3.0']
perl[version='>=5.32.1,<6.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0']
perl-dbd-mysql -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0|>=8.4.0|>=7.5.0']
perl-set-intervaltree -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0']
htslib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=9.3.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9']
perl-perlio-gzip -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0']
unzip -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
perl-set-intervaltree -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0']
perl-perlio-gzip -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.5.0|>=7.2.0']
htslib -> libcurl[version='>=8.2.0,<9.0a0'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0']
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0|>=12|>=9.4.0']
perl-dbi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=9.4.0']
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0|>=4.9']
perl-sereal -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<6.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=11.2.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=7.2.0']
perl-json -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<6.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=11.2.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=7.2.0']
perl-dbi -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0']

Package openssl conflicts for:
perl-dbd-mysql -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1m,<1.1.2a']
htslib -> openssl[version='>=1.1.0,<=1.1.1|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=3.1.0,<4.0a0|>=3.1.1,<4.0a0']
htslib -> libcurl[version='>=8.2.0,<9.0a0'] -> openssl[version='1.0.*|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1s,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1u,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1v,<1.1.2a|>=3.0.10,<4.0a0|>=3.0.9,<4.0a0|>=3.0.8,<4.0a0|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a']
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> htslib[version='>=1.17,<1.19.0a0'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1g,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1h,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1i,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1j,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1k,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1l,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1n,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1q,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1t,<1.1.2a|>=3.1.0,<4.0a0|>=3.1.1,<4.0a0']

Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
perl-json -> perl-json-xs[version='<3'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9']
perl-dbd-mysql -> mysql-connector-c[version='>=6.1.11,<6.1.12.0a0'] -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=11.2.0|>=7.2.0|>=8.4.0|>=7.5.0']
perl-dbd-mysql -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9']
perl-set-intervaltree -> perl-extutils-cppguess -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0']
htslib -> libgcc -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
perl-dbi -> libgcc -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0']
perl-io-compress -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0|>=4.9']
perl-set-intervaltree -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=10.3.0|>=12|>=9.4.0|>=7.3.0']

Package perl conflicts for:
perl-dbd-mysql -> perl-devel-checklib=1.14 -> perl[version='>=5.32.1,<6.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl-bio-asn1-entrezgene -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.22.0,<5.23.0|>=5.32.1,<6.0a0|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-json -> perl[version='>=5.22.0,<5.23.0|>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<6.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-sereal -> perl-sereal-decoder[version='>=4.019'] -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-perlio-gzip -> perl-threaded -> perl
perl-sereal -> perl[version='>=5.22.0,<5.23.0|>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<6.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-text-csv -> perl-test-harness -> perl=5.22.0
perl-io-compress -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0|>=5.22.0,<5.23.0',build=*_perl5]
perl-dbi -> perl-threaded -> perl
perl-set-intervaltree -> perl[version='5.18.2.*|5.22.0.*|>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0|>=5.22.0,<5.23.0',build=*_perl5]
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> perl-bioperl -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.22.0,<5.23.0']
perl[version='>=5.32.1,<6.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-perlio-gzip -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0|>=5.22.0,<5.23.0',build=*_perl5]
perl-dbi -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0|>=5.22.0,<5.23.0',build=*_perl5]
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl[version='>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0']
perl-dbd-mysql -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.22.0,<5.23.0|>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-json -> perl-json-xs[version='<3'] -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-io-compress -> perl-threaded -> perl
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> perl[version='>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<5.33.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-text-csv -> perl[version='>=5.22.0,<5.23.0|>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0|>=5.32.1,<6.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0',build=*_perl5]
perl-set-intervaltree -> perl-threaded -> perl

Package libzlib conflicts for:
htslib -> libzlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
perl-perlio-gzip -> libzlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> libzlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl-bio-samtools -> libzlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']

Package perl-threaded conflicts for:
perl-dbi -> perl-threaded
perl-json -> perl-threaded
perl-set-intervaltree -> perl-threaded
perl-text-csv -> perl-threaded
perl-io-compress -> perl-threaded
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl-bio-asn1-entrezgene -> perl-threaded
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> perl-bioperl -> perl-threaded
perl-perlio-gzip -> perl-threaded
perl-sereal -> perl-threaded
perl-dbd-mysql -> perl-threaded

Package perl-module-build conflicts for:
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl-bio-samtools -> perl-module-build=0.4234
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> perl-module-build[version='0.4232.*|0.4234.*']
perl-set-intervaltree -> perl-extutils-cppguess -> perl-module-build=0.4234

Package libgcc conflicts for:
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> perl-bioperl -> libgcc
perl-io-compress -> perl-scalar-list-utils -> libgcc
htslib -> libgcc
perl-dbi -> libgcc
perl-dbd-mysql -> libgcc
perl-set-intervaltree -> libgcc

Package zlib conflicts for:
htslib -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl-bio-samtools -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.12,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']
perl-io-compress -> perl-compress-raw-zlib -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
perl-perlio-gzip -> zlib[version='1.2.11.*|>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|>=1.2.13,<1.3.0a0']

Package perl-dbi conflicts for:
perl-dbd-mysql -> perl-dbi
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl-bioperl-core==1.007002 -> perl-dbi
perl-dbi

Package htslib conflicts for:
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> htslib[version='>=1.10.2,<1.19.0a0|>=1.12,<1.19.0a0|>=1.14,<1.19.0a0|>=1.16,<1.19.0a0|>=1.17,<1.19.0a0|>=1.9,<1.10.0a0']
htslib

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
perl[version='>=5.32.1,<6.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
perl-io-compress -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
perl-dbi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
perl-perlio-gzip -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
unzip -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
htslib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
perl-set-intervaltree -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
perl-dbd-mysql -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]

Package perl-bioperl conflicts for:
perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> perl-bioperl
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2']

Package perl-parent conflicts for:
perl-io-compress -> perl-encode -> perl-parent
perl-bioperl[version='>=1.7.2'] -> perl-bio-asn1-entrezgene -> perl-parentThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - htslib -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - perl-bio-db-hts[version='>=2.11'] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - perl-dbd-mysql -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - perl-dbi -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - perl-io-compress -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - perl-perlio-gzip -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - perl-set-intervaltree -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.3.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']
  - perl[version='>=5.32.1,<6.0a0',build=*_perl5] -> libgcc-ng[version='>=11.2.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

---

Edited:

after updating the installing command, this is the output:

```
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda ensembl-vep=110
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                             

UnsatisfiableError: 
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

---

Update:

Trying to update with `conda create -c conda-forge -c bioconda ensembl-vep=110 -n vep` created another error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.                                                                                                                                    
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Solving environment: /                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                                                                                                                         
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

UnsatisfiableError:
```

the `UnsatisfiableError` is an empty line.

Using `conda-lock` returned this error:

```
conda-lock install -n vep --file ~/Downloads/conda-lock.yml
/..../miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_config.py:261: UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
* 'allow_mutation' has been removed
  warnings.warn(message, UserWarning)
/.../miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_config.py:261: UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
* 'json_encoders' has been removed
  warnings.warn(message, UserWarning)

Usage: conda-lock install [OPTIONS] [LOCK_FILE]
Try 'conda-lock install --help' for help.

Error: No such option: --file Did you mean --auth-file?
```

I tried the `--auth-file` still got the same error but without the usage part.

thanks again

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77281095/how-to-install-bioconda-packages/77281096#77281096

Comment: thank you! tried it, but still shows it found conflicts without really listing them. I'm suspecting that is related to vep itself.

Comment: Please edit the question then to show the new attempt using `conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda ensembl-vep`. The old attempt with the improper call (`-c bioconda` only) can be deleted. Also, does it work to create a new environment, i.e., `conda create ...`?

Comment: Just edited as suggested. Not sure however why it is improper? since the `conda install -c bioconda ensembl-vep` is the recommended way on anaconda page and the conda-forge is already in the local channel list for this enviroment: ```conda config --show channels
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

Comment: Great. The issue is that the instructions on the Anaconda Cloud page are automatically generated and the repository does not provide any API for individual channels to configure what is displayed. For many channels it displays substandard installation recommendations, the worst of which is stuff like `-c conda-forge/label/broken` - literally encouraging users to install broken versions of packages.

Comment: thank you very much for the clarification. I'm still unable to download the latest version.

Comment: Does the new environment work? I.e., `conda create -c conda-forge -c bioconda ensembl-vep=110`

Comment: I observe no problem installing it in fresh environments for `linux-64` and `osx-64` platforms. For example, a prefix.dev solve yields [this conda-lock YAML](https://prefix.dev//envs/mfansler/so-ensembl-vep/cub819tcyhsh/conda-lock.yml). I.e., something about your current environment or configuration are incompatible with installing that version.

Comment: thank you for answering and sorry for the delay. Both approaches give me different errors. I updated the question, since it is really lengthy

Comment: I'm wondering, how come both osx and linux have the same issue? could it be some other dependency is missing?

Comment: Your Conda Lock command is a syntax error - follow the directions and drop the `--file`. There might be something with the `perl-dbd-mysql` needing to be rerendered (I’ll check). Is your **base** environment updated? Maybe consider using Mamba instead - it often gives better failure messages.

Comment: Thanks a zillion, on linux with conda-lock the newest release of vep was finally installed. On osx, however, I got an informative error, which is osx-arm64 not supported. I added it in the platform section I got the same "allow-mutation" & "json" error, yet the env was created without vep installed.

Comment: Bioconda doesn't build for **osx-arm64**, but you can still install **osx-64** environments on Apple Silicon by setting the platform explicitly (or `CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64`).