# How to install Bioconda packages

Tags: conda, bioinformatics, conda-forge

This is a generic formulation of a common question. I am trying to install package `foo` from Bioconda. I attempt:

```
conda install -c bioconda foo
```

However, this leads to either unsatisifiable dependencies or if it does solve leads to shared object errors at runtime.

Why doesn't this work and what is the correct solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Conda Forge must be prioritized

The Bioconda channel builds packages with the Conda Forge channel prioritized. This requires users to likewise prioritize the Conda Forge channel when installing Bioconda packages (see [Bioconda documentation](https://bioconda.github.io/#usage)). That is, the correct formulation for specifying channels at install time is:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge -c bioconda foo
```

---

## Additional Notes

#### Global configuration and Anaconda

The Bioconda channel recommends that users configure their channels globally to have Conda Forge prioritized.

**Global Bioconda configuration (not for Anaconda users)**

```bash
conda config --add channels defaults
conda config --add channels bioconda
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

However, please note that *this is fundamentally incompatible with Anaconda **base***. Subsequent solves in Anaconda **base** will be crippled when solving for the huge number of `anaconda` packages in the vast search space of Conda Forge. Users who intend to configure Conda Forge as their priority should install a base such as Miniforge, which is preconfigured for this setup.

Anaconda users who do not want to replace their **base** instead can configure channels per environment by using the `--env` argument.

**Example: prioritize `conda-forge` in one environment**

```bash
conda create -n bioenv
conda activate bioenv
conda config --env --add channels bioconda
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
```

All subsequent installations *must have the environment activated* to use this environment-specific configuration.

### Prefer YAML

*Ad hoc* installations with `conda install` can lead to difficult to reproduce environments and also waste time solving. A better approach is to define environments using YAML files.

**Example: rnaseq.yaml**

```
name: rnaseq
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - nodefaults  ## ignore user settings
dependencies:
  ## alignment/quantification
  - salmon

  ## R (CRAN)
  - r-base=4.3
  - r-tidyverse
  - r-magrittr
  - r-pheatmap

  ## R (Bioconductor)
  - bioconductor-deseq2
  - bioconductor-tximeta
  - bioconductor-tximport
```

which can be used to create an environment with

```
conda env create -n rnaseq -f rnaseq.yaml
```