# Samtools not working, but installing, because of libdeflate?

Tags: conda, samtools

I have a problem reading my bam files with samtools.
Whenever I try to run the code

```
samtools view your_file.bam
```

it tells me

```
dyld[69540]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libdeflate.so
  Referenced from: <D6D57EAF-7BCE-33F1-B9CE-57A7A42BD16D> /Users/faleevamaria/anaconda3/envs/ARTDeco/bin/samtools
  Reason: tried: '/Users/faleevamaria/anaconda3/envs/ARTDeco/bin/../lib/libdeflate.so' (no such file), '/Users/faleevamaria/anaconda3/envs/ARTDeco/bin/../lib/libdeflate.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libdeflate.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libdeflate.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
Abort trap: 6
```

Following this back, I tried to check
`samtools --version`
and got the same error message (even though I see the updated package when I type in conda list)

I then tried to check the library path:
`otool -L /Users/faleevamaria/anaconda3/envs/ARTDeco/bin/samtools`

and got:

```
/Users/faleevamaria/anaconda3/envs/ARTDeco/bin/samtools:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
    @rpath/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
    @rpath/libbz2.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/liblzma.5.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.3.0)
    @rpath/libdeflate.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
    @rpath/libncursesw.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    @rpath/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

I think the problem is with the libdeflate.so, which says its not installed (even though I also see the updated version in my conda list).

I have tried all variations of libderflate and samtools installation/reinstallation, but nothing seems to be doing the trick. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ensure that all packages are from Conda Forge or Bioconda (check `conda list`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/77281096/570918

Comment: Also, please show the `conda list` for the environment in the question body. If it is too long, then show just the pertinent subset, e.g., `conda list -c '(samtools|libdeflate)'`.